# Terraform Scripts for Hierarchal partition keys in Cosmos

Tags: azure, terraform, azure-cosmosdb, azure-cosmosdb-sqlapi

I want to create a container who has hierarchical partition keys.

Here is example terraform scripts to create container

```
resource "azurerm_cosmosdb_sql_container" "container_name" {
  name                  = "name"
  resource_group_name   = data.azurerm_resource_group.snowflake.name
  account_name          = azurerm_cosmosdb_account.cosmosdb.name
  database_name         = azurerm_cosmosdb_sql_database.db.name
  partition_key_path    = ["/location_id","/x_id"]
  partition_key_version = 2
  throughput            = 400
  unique_key {
    paths = ["/x_name", "/x_source"]
  }
}
```

But its not supported yet for creation of hierarchical keys.

Getting below error when running terraform validate

```
Error: Incorrect attribute value type

  on cosmos.tf line 78, in resource "azurerm_cosmosdb_sql_container" "status_by_location_id":
  78:   partition_key_path    = ["/location_id", "/x_id"]

Inappropriate value for attribute "partition_key_path": string required.
```

Can someone help on this ?

Comment: Try this script - resource "azurerm_cosmosdb_sql_container" "container_name" {
  name                  = "name"
  resource_group_name   = data.azurerm_resource_group.snowflake.name
  account_name          = azurerm_cosmosdb_account.cosmosdb.name
  database_name         = azurerm_cosmosdb_sql_database.db.name
  partition_key_path    = ["/TenantId","/UserId","/SessionId"]
  partition_key_version = 2
  throughput            = 400
  unique_key {
    paths = ["/x_name", "/x_source"]
  }
}

Comment: Its same as I mentioned in the question, its not supported yet @SiddheshDesai

Comment: The error resolved with this script on my end, can you check? - partition_key_path    = "/TenantId,/UserId,/SessionId" refer here - https://i.imgur.com/oJoG6Aj.png

Comment: Let me check once

Comment: @SiddheshDesai 

getting this error when trying to apply terraform scripts. Can I know which version you are using of azurerm ?

I have added this to my provider file :  ~> 3.41.0

Code="BadRequest" Message="Message: {\"code\":\"BadRequest\",\"message\":\"Message: {\\\"Errors\\\":[\\\"The partition key component definition path '\\\\/location_id,\\\\/event_id' could not be accepted, failed near position '12'. Partition key paths must contain only valid characters and not contain a trailing slash or wildcard character.\\\"]}

Answer (score 0):

Terraform Scripts for Hierarchal partition keys in Cosmos]

```vhdl
Inappropriate value for attribute "partition_key_path": string required
```

Terraform does not support hierarchical partition keys in cosmos DB. hierarchical partition keys are **supported only in the .NET v3 SDK, the Java v4 SDK, and the preview version of the JavaScript SDK**

Follow the [MS Doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/hierarchical-partition-keys?tabs=net-v3,arm-json#limitations-and-known-issues)  & [MS Doc1](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/hierarchical-partition-keys?tabs=net-v3,arm-json) to check that containers that use hierarchical partition keys.

When I tried to create containers using hierarchical partition keys, I encountered the same error

[image]

I created a **Cosmos DB SQL database with a container** using the below Terraform code

```
    provider "azurerm" {
      features {}
    }
    
    resource "azurerm_resource_group" "example" {
      name     = "db-rg"
      location = "WestIndia"
    }

    resource "azurerm_cosmosdb_account" "example" {
      name                      = "sample-account"
      location                  = azurerm_resource_group.example.location
      resource_group_name       = azurerm_resource_group.example.name
      offer_type                = "Standard"
      kind                      = "GlobalDocumentDB"
      enable_automatic_failover = false
      geo_location {
        location          = azurerm_resource_group.example.location
        failover_priority = 0
      }
      consistency_policy {
        consistency_level       = "BoundedStaleness"
        max_interval_in_seconds = 300
        max_staleness_prefix    = 100000
      }
      depends_on = [
        azurerm_resource_group.example
      ]
    }
    
    resource "azurerm_cosmosdb_sql_database" "main" {
      name                = "sampledab"
      resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.example.name
      account_name        = azurerm_cosmosdb_account.example.name
      autoscale_settings {
        max_throughput = 1000
      }
    }
    
    resource "azurerm_cosmosdb_sql_container" "example" {
      name                  = "venkatdb"
      resource_group_name   = azurerm_resource_group.example.name
      account_name          = azurerm_cosmosdb_account.example.name
      database_name         = azurerm_cosmosdb_sql_database.main.name
      partition_key_path    = "/definition/id"
      throughput            = 400
      partition_key_version = 1
      unique_key {
        paths = ["/definition/idlong", "/definition/idshort"]
      }
    
    }
    resource "random_pet" "prefix" {
      prefix = "cosmos-db-autoscale"
      length = 1
    }
```

**Terraform apply:**

[image]

Once the above container has been successfully created.

[image]

Refer the `SQL Container within a Cosmos DB Account` module in [Terraform registry](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/azurerm/3.33.0/docs/resources/cosmosdb_sql_container.html)